# Developer Story - Let us order the list?

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

On my developer story there's a list of accomplishments (not sure what it's called).

Mine's got literally 10+ screens of open source contributions until it gets to my work experience. I'd really like to be able to emphasize what I think is most likely to lead to a job, not whatever random open source projects I contributed a patch too.

Have you considered adding the ability to choose an order or give a priority to each item so we can move relevant info to the top?

...and before you tell me just remove those open source projects ... I do think they have a point ... they show I contribute and submit patches which I think is a selling point. It's just not the nearly the most important info. That info is currently buried at the bottom of a very long page.

From [your blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/10/bye-bye-bullets-the-stack-overflow-developer-story-is-the-new-technical-resume/?cb=1)

> The Developer Story puts the work you’re most proud of where it belongs..

Not as far as I can tell. See above

> It’s your story; tell it your way.

It's not currently possible to tell it my way. See above

Comment: A few different users have brought up the reordering of items on the timeline.  We're currently looking at several solutions for it.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I would prefer to have actual jobs always above any contributions/projects of my own. Currently, they're buried quite deep, and that's after being employed at one company for only three years. Imagine if I work at the same company for ten years: you'd have to scroll several pages down to even see it!

Comment: We're currently reviewing the ordering of items on the timeline and looking at how we can give users greater flexibility to highlight or group certain items. I'll keep you posted with progress.

Comment: I hope this goes for the reading section, too?  A quick drag-n-drop feature would be nice...

Comment: This needs a higher priority.  My most recent whole-project accomplishments are 3/4 of the way down the list.  Stuff I committed a few changes to 13 years ago are higher up.  Simply makes for a bad story!

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Developer Story feature no longer exists.